# Curved brick wall

Tags: lateral-thinking, real

Below is a fully functioning curved brick wall. Amazingly it uses fewer bricks than a functioning straight brick wall of comparable length. How is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In the curved wall, the curves provides strength.  In a straight wall of comparable length, one could probably push the wall over.  To make a viable wall, several layers are needed, which requires a lot more bricks.
>
>  "lateral-thinking" -- it needs lateral strength.  :-)

Comment: You got it! Well done.

Comment: Nice catch on `lateral-thinking`!  rot13: Gur pbeehtngvba nyfb urycf cerirag gur jnyy sebz ohpxyvat.

Comment: Hayrff gubfr ner fbzr ernyyl znffvir gerrf, gur jnyy vf bayl n srj srrg gnyy. V qba'g frr ubj n fvatyr jvqgu jbhyq or gbb jrnx.